# Filtering using "in" between two linked tables in Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, ssas, business-intelligence

I have two tables named qoutes and sales and these two tables are associated with customerid. I want to count the records in my Qoutes table by grouping them by month and day, but while doing this, I want to count only the values ​​of customer IDs with GP > 0 in the sales table. In other words, I want to filter the customerid values returned from another table by using "in" in a calculate query in which I use the Countrows function. Thanks in advance :)

```
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS('Qoutes'),
    RELATEDTABLE('Sales'),
    'Sales'[GP] > 0,
    'Sales'[customerid] IN VALUES('Qoutes'[customerid]),
    VALUES('Qoutes'[Month]),
    VALUES('Qoutes'[Day])
)
```

There are 15 customerids in the Sales Table in the given date range, but there are 10 customerids with Gp > 0. I want to count the values ​​of these 10 customerids in my Qoutes table.

Comment: Please share a snip of your data model. Would like see the relationships for `Quotes`, `Sales`, `Customer`? and also your Date table if you have one. And is your DAX expression above for a Calculated Column (if yes, which table) or Measure? Not sure I understand the grouping by month/day. Please update your question with this info and a snip of your desired visual if relevant.

Comment: Hi, yes this will be a measure. Let me share the dax I used in another test, maybe it will be clearer.

```Temp Measure:=

CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(
        GROUPBY('Qoutes', 'Qoutes'[Month], 'Qoutes'[Day])
       ),
    FILTER(
        'Sales',
        'Sales'[GP] > 0 && 'Sales'[DealerKey] IN VALUES('Qoutes'[DealerKey])
    )
)```

Comment: It isn't clearer, please share a snip of your data model. If the two tables have a relationship, I am unsure why you need to do the `IN VALUES` part. Show us what you have and what you, provide a couple sample tables or even a sample PBIX.

Answer (score 0):

```
Quote Count:
  var salesV = CALCULATE(VALUES('Sales'[customerid]), 'Sales'[GP] > 0)
  RETURN CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Quotes'), 'Quotes'[cusomterid] IN salesV)
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?